# Computing probabilities for each value of a random variable

Tags: probability, combinations

Assume you have a bag of 6 marbles, 2 of which are red and 4 of which are blue, and let the random variable Y represent the number of red marbles drawn after 3 are taken from the bag.

I'm trying to compute the probability for each value of Y.

What I've attempted:

Total number of combinations: ${}_6 \mathrm{ C }_3 = {6 \choose 3} = \frac{6!}{3!(6-3)!} = 20$

$P(Y = 0) = \frac{4 \choose 3}{20} = \frac{4}{20}$ (because there are four blue marbles in the bag and we are looking for the combinations of drawing three of these four)

$P(Y = 1) = 2\times\frac{4 \choose 2}{20} = \frac{12}{20}$ (because if you draw one red marble you have to draw two blue marbles from the bag to get Y = 1)

$P(Y = 2) = \frac{4 \choose 1}{20} = \frac{4}{20}$ (because if you draw two red marbles you have to draw one blue marble from the four in the bag to get Y = 2)

Have I done this correctly? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Well, shouldn't these sum to $1$?

Comment: Try computing $\Pr(Y=1)$ again

Comment: I don't understand your computation for $Y=1$.  In that case you must choose one red ($2$ ways to do it ) and two blue ($\binom 42= 6$ ways to do it).  Hence the probability is $\frac {12}{20}$.

Comment: In general, if you have $r$ red marbles and $s$ blue marbles, with $n = (r + s)$ and if you draw $k \leq \min(r,s)$ marbles, without replacement, then you can compute the probability of drawing exactly $a \in \{0,1,\cdots,k\}$ red marbles out of the $k$ as $$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}$$ **by stretching your intuition**.  There are $$D = \binom{n}{k}$$   ways that the $k$ marbles can be drawn.  There are $$N = \binom{r}{a} \times \binom{s}{k-a}$$ ways of drawing $a$ out of $r$ red marbles and $(k-a)$ out of $s$ blue marbles.

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly different way of doing it, and my results are the same as yours.

$P(Y=0)=\frac{4\times 3\times 2}{6\times 5\times 4}=\frac{1}{5}$

$P(Y=1)=3\times \frac{2\times 4\times 3}{6\times 5\times 4}=\frac{3}{5}$

$P(Y=2)=3\times \frac{2\times 1\times 4}{6\times 5\times 4}=\frac{1}{5}$